# How to show delete button in UITableViewCell without swiping/touching it like in Moda Operandi iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I saw this effect in Moda Operandi app in ios when click on cart icon. When I click on cart button products are loaded in tableview and delete button is shown without swiping the cell. Please guide me on how can I do this in my app.

Using delegate methods I am able to show the delete button when I swipe from right to left and able to delete row but how can I show delete the button like I saw this effect in Moda Operandi app in ios when click on cart icon. When I click on cart button products are loaded in tableview and delete button is shown without swiping the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native `UITableViewRowAction` does not support that, but you could write your own implementation or use a library.

e.g This one: [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell),

Implement the cells and the delegate according to the documentation, then use the `showSwipe` method to display the swipe actions programmatically.